# State Propagation Good Practices and "orphanRemoval" relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I saw when working with bidirectional relationships, it is a good practice to create add and remove methods on the referenced/not owning side of the relationship because the database only works with unidirectional relationships and that allows to avoid propagation state problems (ie: when the state of database and object model are unsynced).

So, when having for example: A video can have any comments and a comment can belong to a single video

Mapped this way:

- A video entity (OneToMany): not owning side and also the parent entity/table
- A comment entity (ManyToOne): owning side and also the children table

This definitions above implicitly imply that (with Hibernate) we have:

- A video class with a List of comments annotated with @OneToMany(mappedBy = "video")
- A comment class with a property type Video named "video" annotated with @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn

Would be a good practice to add on the Video entity:

```
addComment(Comment c) {
// adds to the list
c.setVideo(this) // updates the comment "c"
} 

removeComment(Comment c) {
// removes from the list
c.setVideo(null)
}
```

Now here comes the question:

If the necessity of add and remove methods on the Video entity is to make sure the Comment object is synced and therefore the database (because the database works only from owning side -> not owning side), when using the "orphanRemoval" argument on the @OneToMany side does the Hibernate performs this under the hood (sync Comment object with the changes performed in the Video entity)?

Because orphanRemoval = true says to Hibernate to delete all the children rows of the Children entity/table (comment entity) that its FK field (ie parent's table reference) is null (basically a ON SET NULL DELETE (i know this trigger doesn't exist)) So if a video sets its  list of comments to null, all comments that were on this list are also set to null and would be deleted.

So, does hibernate implement a sort of "removeComment" (specially the "c.setVideo(this) // updates the comment "c"" part) method under the hood to implement this the same way and method the good practice mentions to do?

Answer (score 0):

What hibernate does when doing `orphanRemoval` is the following:

Assume you have a video with 2 comments [comment id=1] [comment id=2]

So when you delete the video, Hibernate issues delete stmt on that video
e.g `delete from video where id=1`
after that all comments become orphans, since their parent (video) is deleted
So hibernate checks if `orphanRemoval` feature is enabled, if so, it issues a delete stmt for all children one by one so for that example it will execute the following:

```
delete from comment where id=1;
delete from comment where id=2;
```

So this is what happens under the hood.

So you might ask why you need to sync the bidirectional entities, and whether hibernate will call these functions, and the answer to that is No, remember hibernate proxy the entity and does its magic with that proxy

Hibernate will not use these adders/removals functions. So what the heck is entity sync and why it is important, to give you a simple answer is that you need to simulate what hibernate going to do, in your code since you don't know for sure when exactly hibernate will run these queries since hibernate has an auto flush mode

For the above example:
Imagine you don't do the sync part so you have just setters and getters and you deleted the video, and then you did anything with `video.getComments()` like for example imagine following code

```
repo.delete(video);
if (video.getComments().size() == 0) {
    // blabla
}
```

So if you have not removed these comments yourself via syncing, `video.getComments()` will still contain data thus you could have faced wrong code decisions.